# How to correctly translate sql-code in Delphi

Tags: sql, delphi, firebird

In sql-editor this code works fine:

```
Select *
from Journal
where status<>'D' 
order by JDate,J_ID
```

but couldn't write correct code in Delphi.

**1)**

```
dstJournal.Close;
dstJournal.SQL.Clear;
dstJournal.SQL.CommaText:='Select * from Journal  order by JDate,J_ID';
```

> sql error code=-104: Token Unknown J_ID

if I write only 'order by JDate' or only 'oder by J_ID' then it works.

**2)** 
if I write:

```
dstJournal.SQL.CommaText:='Select * from Journal where Status<>"D" ';
```

> it gets error:sql error code=-206:Column Unknown D.

I tried 'D' but delphi couldn't compile and shows "missing operator or semicolon" message.

How to write correct delphi code?

Comment: Is that one double-quote each side of `D` or two single quotes?  It should be two single quotes to indicate that D is a value not a column name.

Comment: @J... no, it is a SQL thing.

Comment: @RemyLebeau ...yeah, my bad.  I mostly work in MySQL and double quotes are fine there, at least with ANSI_QUOTES turned off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use [`CommaText`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStrings.CommaText).  It is for parsing SDF formatted (quoted, comma delimited) text into or out of a `TStrings` object. That's not what you're doing, so don't use that.

Set the [`Text`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Text) instead:

```
dstJournal.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM Journal WHERE status <> ''D'' ORDER BY JDate, J_ID';
```

Or use the [`Add()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Add) method:

```
dstJournal.SQL.Clear;
dstJournal.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM Journal');
dstJournal.SQL.Add('WHERE status <> ''D''');
dstJournal.SQL.Add('ORDER BY JDate, J_ID');
```

> I tried 'D' but delphi couldn't compile: missing operator or semicolon.

Delphi strings are enclosed with single quotes so if you mean to put them into your query you have to escape them by using two single quotes.

```
  dstJournal.SQL.Add('WHERE status <> ''D''');
```

Comment: @basti don't edit your question after you've asked it - it's now a different question altogether.  If you have a new question after your first question is resolved, ask a new question instead.

Comment: J...  I write:
dstJournal.Sql.Add('Select * from Journal where STATUS<>"D" order by JDate,J_ID'); 
Error: Column unknown D

Comment: J.., I know. Field name is STATUS. For this reason I write STATUS but I receive the same error.

Comment: Because `'D'` data should better not be splined into the SQL code. Keep programs and data separated by using SQL parameters. http://bobby-tables.com/ and https://github.com/petdance/bobby-tables/issues/98

Comment: @J... `Firebird is case sensitive [about table and column names] by default, I believe` - no, it is not. If you use SQL dialect 3 (which you should after 1999) you can force FB into case-sensitivity by putting identifiers in doublequotes, thus those would be 3 difference columns: `Select ... "status", "Status", "STATUS" from...` but without escaping (or in dialect 1 that didn't support it) the identifiers are all uppercased becoming case-insensitive.

Comment: @Arioch'The Good to know.  I don't know why I thought that about firebird, then.

Comment: Well, won't it be just a violation of SQL standard if some SQL-server is case-sensitive by default?

Comment: @Arioch'The I don't know... it wouldn't be the first time that standards were loosely applied across disjoint, quasi-proprietary implementations of an ideal.  That kind of thing wouldn't surprise me.